# What programming language is indicated to produce interactive videos?

Tags: programming-languages

By interactive videos I mean the following proccess:

An video starts playing. After some time, the video is paused and two button are exhibited on the videoscreen. If the user selects the first button, then It starts to play video B. If the second button is chosen instead, then it starts playing video C.
The process are repeated several times. The video that is resumed depends on the  users button decision.

It all is exhibit on a website, much like an YouTube video.

What are the programming languages that could be used to create the video interactivity?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: IMHO the best path to chose is: using HTML + JS + CSS

Comment: "It all is exhibit on a website, much like an YouTube video." - It's likely either Flash or some combo of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.

Comment: Any language, really, but if you don't want to reinvent too many wheels, use one for which there already exists a usable web framework.

Answer (score 1):

You have several solution to adopt if you want everything client side:

1. A combination of HTML, Javascript and CSS is the first the comes in my mind because you are already on a web page. HTML can handle the [playback of videos](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp), while JS handles the interaction of buttons that are styled through CSS.
2. Flash is a possible solution, but I tend to avoid it since major browser are dropping it.
3. Using a Game Engine that allows to export Games in Web Browser as a WebGL project: Unity or Unreal can do the job (e.g. [for unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html)).
4. If you like to reinvent the wheel you can go directly with WebGL (but I'm not confident with it, so I don't know if it is a good suggestion, but at least it is possible to [animate textures with a video](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Animating_textures_in_WebGL))

or any other language can do the job (but you will always have to pass through HTML+JS+CSS).